# Retrieve documents with matching values on a given field in mongodb

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

Let's say I have the following two documents:

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5d1faa57a370cc52f0614313"), "bucket" : [ [2, 3], [ 111, 111 ]]}

{ "_id" : ObjectId("6d1faa57a370cc52f0614311"), "bucket" : [ [2, 3], [ 999, 999 ]]}
```

Both documents share the `[2,3]` value on the `bucket field`.

How can I retrieve such documents from a mongodb collection? Is this even possible?

Sorry if the question is stupid, I'm a mongo newbie.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's possible. You just need to pass the matching argument inside find().

```
db.getCollection('test').find({"bucket" :[2,3]})
```

[I have provided an image link for your reference.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r786p.png)